# Recursive concurrency with golang

Tags: go, concurrency

I'd like to distribute some load across some goroutines. If the number of tasks is known beforehand then it is easy to organize. For example, I could do fan out with a wait group.

```
nTasks := 100
nGoroutines := 10

// it is important that this channel is not buffered
ch := make(chan *Task)
done := make(chan bool)
var w sync.WaitGroup
// Feed the channel until done
go func () {
    for i:= 0; i < nTasks; i++ {
        task := getTaskI(i)
        ch <- task
    }
    // as ch is not buffered once everything is read we know we have delivered all of them
    for i:=0; i < nGoroutines; i++ {
        done <- false
    }
}()
for i:= 0; i < nGoroutines; i ++ {
    w.Add(1)
    go func () {
        defer w.Done()
        select {
        case task := <-ch:
            doSomethingWithTask(task)
        case <- done:
            return
        }
    }()
}
w.Wait()
// All tasks done, all goroutines closed
```

However, in my case each task returns more tasks to be done. Say for example a crawler where we receive all the links from the crawled web. My initial hunch was to have a main loop where I track the number of tasks done and tasks pending. When I'm done I send a finish signal to all goroutines:

```
nGoroutines := 10
ch := make(chan *Task, nGoroutines)
feedBackChannel := make(chan * Task, nGoroutines)
done := make(chan bool)

for i:= 0; i < nGoroutines; i ++ {
    go func () {
        select {
        case task := <-ch:
            task.NextTasks = doSomethingWithTask(task)
            feedBackChannel <- task
        case <- done:
            return
        }
    }()
}

// seed first task
ch <- firstTask
nTasksRemaining := 1

for nTasksRemaining > 0 {
    task := <- feedBackChannel
    nTasksRemaining -= 1
    for _, t := range(task.NextTasks) {
        ch <- t
        nTasksRemaining++
    }
}
for i:=0; i < nGoroutines; i++ {
    done <- false
}
```

However, this produces a deadlock. For example if NextTasks is bigger than the number of goroutines then the main loop will stall when the first tasks finish. But the first tasks can't finish because the feedBack is blocked since the mainLoop is waiting to write.

One "easy" way out of this is to post to the channel asynchronously:
Instead of doing `feedBackChannel <- task` do `go func () {feedBackChannel <- task}()`. Now, this feels like an awful hack. Specially since there might be hundred of thousands of tasks.

What would be a nice way to avoid this deadlock? I've searched for concurrency patterns, but mostly are simpler things like fanning out or pipelines where the later stage does not affect the earlier steps.

Comment: Your description is a bit too complex to comprehend fully but there are 2 notes I have. 1. You incorrectly do waitGroup.Add() inside goroutine, it should be done before calling it. I usually call defer waitGroup.Done() immediately once goroutine started. 2. It's not clear why you need feedbackChannel. To me it looks you need simply spawn new grorutines as needed and in the main thread do watGroup.Wait(). But I may be missing some requirements.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok Spawning new goroutines would work, but I suppose reusing goroutines and limiting the amount of them will consume less resources, right? In my case I'm expecting in the order of hundred of thousands tasks. (BTW, I've fixed the wait Group)

Comment: Go routines are very light, it's usual to spawn millions of goroutines without any issues. Though you can have a look into rate limiting pattern https://gobyexample.com/rate-limiting

Comment: Goroutines are very lightweight. I would at least test how much resources your program takes before getting fancy. Usually hundreds of thousands of simultaneously running goroutines isn't any kind of problem.

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim goroutines have quite low overhead and I've found it relatively painless to manage similar work queues by just spawning goroutines instead of trying to manage the work myself. On the other hand it was on the order of thousands, not hundreds of thousands, so it might not apply to your case. But give it a try, it could work and that would make your code so much simpler.

Comment: Oh, and if you do actually run into memory problems because of too many active goroutines (which usually means millions). The simplest way to limit them would be to use runtime.NumGoroutine() to check how many are currently running before spawning a new one and sleep for a while if there's too many. Trying to reuse them is very rarely worth it.

Comment: You can use a worker pool (https://github.com/dc0d/workerpool).

Comment: Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46386353/understanding-correct-use-of-channels-in-golang-concurrent-context/46458118#46458118) with worker-pool example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, your solution is pretty complex. Here are some points. Hope it helps.

- As people mentioned in comments, launching a goroutine is cheap (both memory and switch between them is much cheaper that OS level theread) and you could have hundred thousand of them. Let's assume for some reasons you want to have worker goroutines.
- Instead of done channel you could just close `ch` channel and instead of `select` you just `range` over your channel getting tasks.
- I don't see the point of separating `ch` and `feedBackChannel` just push every task you have into `ch` and increase its capacity.
- As mentioned you may get a deadlock when you trying to enqueue new task. My solution is pretty naive. Just increase its capacity until you are sure that it won't overflow (you could also log warnings if `cap(ch) - len(ch) < threshold`). If you create a channel (of pointers) with 1 million capacity it will take about `8 * 1e6 ~= 8MB` of ram.

Comment: I thought of the feedBackChannel of a way to keep track of how many tasks are left. I can't just do a select with a default because that would mean that if I'm short of tasks at some point then goroutines would start to close. That's why I tried to centralize it in only one task.


Buffering the channel a lot could actually be quite feasible. As you say the  memory footprint of the channel is really small.

In my particular case the task that I want to do are **not** IO, but rather CPU (it is parallelizing some indexing), so opening goroutines all the time will probably have an impact.

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim Don't know it fits your problem or not, you could get task count with `len(ch)` if you merge all channels in `ch`. I'll try to add a code sample if I had the time later.